# Custom Metric and Dimension For Firebase Analytics - iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, analytics, metrics, dimensions

I'm facing problems with migration from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics. Can't find how to set Custom Dimensions and metrics.
As refer to this [Link](https://growthbug.com/i-took-firebase-analytics-for-a-ride-heres-the-conclusion-8a148a2e6229), they said that we can use 'User properties' as a replacement for Custom Dimension but still can't find how to set Custom metrics to firebase analytics yet. 
is that even possible ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you find answer here? Also facing the same problem with Firebase after 24 hrs my dimensions still did not show on Firebase Console

Comment: No sorry, I didn't. :(